# Create regular number in a loop using MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I want to get a new value of CC with every iteration. CC is a 3-dimensional matrix having stored 200 2-dimensional but I can't use another loop to get the new value of CC. CC is `6*6*200` 3-dimensional matrix. I am trying to do in this way but now working

```
for j = 1:100
    for i = 1:2
        K = B'*CC(j*i)*B;
    end
end
```

In this way, I get `CC = 1,2,2,4,3,6...` with each iteration but I want to get value of `CC` continuous like `j=1, i=1` I get `CC(1)` then `j=1 i=2, CC(2), j=2, i=1, CC(3), j=2,i=2, CC(4)....` and in last `j=100, i=1, CC(199), j=100, i=2, CC(200)`.

The above code is just an example to show the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get your described desired results you can do `CC((j-1)*2+i)`, but from your description it looks like you rather want `CC(:,:,(j-1)*2+i)`